# Set iron-ajax parameter from a shadow root

Tags: ajax, polymer, shadow-dom

I would like to create an element which changes the parameters of an iron-ajax element located in another root (its parent)

Parent:

```
<iron-ajax id="ajaxService"
auto
url="http://..."
method="GET"
handle-as="json"
params="{{ajaxParams}}"
last-response="{{datas}}"></iron-ajax>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[datas]]">
        <div>[[item]]</div>
    </template>
```

and the child:

```
<dom-module id="my-pagination">
<template>
<style include="shared-styles">
:host {
  display: block;
}

.disabledButton
{
  color: #DDDDDD;
}
</style>

<div class="horizontal center layout">
  <div class="flex"></div>
  <span>
    <span id="rangeStart"></span>-<span id="rangeEnd"></span> sur <span>[[data.total_count]]</span>
  </span>
  <paper-icon-button id="prevPage" class="disabledButton" icon="mdi:chevron-left" on-tap="prevPage" disabled></paper-icon-button>
  <paper-icon-button id="nextPage" icon="mdi:chevron-right" on-tap="nextPage"></paper-icon-button>
</div>
```

```
  Polymer({
is: 'my-pagination',
properties: {
  ajaxId: String,
  offset: {
    type: Number,
    value: 0
  },
  limit: {
    type: Number,
    value: 6
  },
  usersAjaxParams: {
    type: String,
    computed: "processParams(offset, limit)"
  }
},
processParams: function (offset, limit) {
  return {
        offset: offset,
        limit: limit,
    };
},
computeRange: function (offset, limit, nodeRangeStart, nodeRangeEnd) {
  nodeRangeStart.innerText = offset;
  nodeRangeEnd.innerText = offset + limit;
},
prevPage: function () {
  this.offset = this.offset - this.limit;
  this.computeRange(this.offset, this.limit, this.$.rangeStart, this.$.rangeEnd);
  };
},
nextPage: function () {
// pretty much same code as above, but for the "next" page
  }
},
attached: function () {
  this.computeRange(this.offset, this.limit, this.$.rangeStart, this.$.rangeEnd);
}
});
```

So what I am trying to achieve here is to create a '' element which i could use by providing the ajax node ID as property, and the pagination element would change the ajax parameters whenever I click the "next" or "previous" page button.

And while we're at it, how I can pass datas to the child as weel? (I will need '[[data.total_count]]' later on)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'd use events to let the parent element know a parameter has changed
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#custom-events

Comment: OR 2way bind ajaxParams to the child

Comment: well letting `iron-ajax` knows that something has changed is not much of a problem, since the "auto" property checks for this and will fire the ajax call. My real problem is about transmitting these parameters values from the shadow root to the `iron-ajax`

Comment: You 'fire' it to the parent element that contains the child and iron-ajax. Then let that element make the changes. Events should go up never down or sideways. To do something downwards just call a method or change a property.